# How to read a file from a website using objective-c & xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to write a code that will grab some information provided by my server (remote), for example request a url that will return data that will be represented in the application after parsing it.

I've been trying since 2 days now I googled it i found some incomplete solution but nothing really worked out for me

I am really noob in Xcode and Objective-C

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Click](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) for the URL-Loading documentation provided by Apple.
Especially `Using NSURLConnection` looks interesting for you.

Edit: 
Another *very* good and easy-to-use Framework for this task is ASIHTTP:
[Click](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

The easiest way:

```
- (void)grabURL
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
  ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request startSynchronous];
  NSError *error = [request error];
  if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
  }
}
```

Asynchronous loading is only slightly more complex:

```
- (void)grabURLInBackground
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

Comment: @bhappy Do it the first way since you are a noob.  It'll work for just about whatever you want to do.

Comment: ahaha +1 for both synchronous and asynchronous examples but mainly for the alleseeing-i url lol!! ;) awesome!