# Extract content from UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, uitextview, extract, article

I have an RSS-feed that loads articles from some sites. I want the text in the articles to be shown in a TextView. It's not ads in the articles, so I am allowed to just get the text. Anyone knows how I can do it?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `UIWebView` to read from a URL.

Why not just open a connection to the URL and download the text? You can parse/filter/etc the raw data before putting it in your TextView.

See these other SO questions for examples of how to do this:

- [Simple method to read XML from a URL - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797996/simple-method-to-read-xml-from-a-url-iphone)
- [How to read a file from a website using objective-c & xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531514/how-to-read-a-file-from-a-website-using-objective-c-xcode)

Comment: Thank you! This was excactly what I was looking for.